# Angular in modal. Can't figure out what is wrong with my controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am pretty new to angular and can't for the life of me figure out what is wrong with this bit of code. I would be happy to supply more code as is needed.

The issue is that none of the angular actions are happening. The table does not get populated and none of the buttons do anything. The http get never makes it to my server. So, I was wondering if anyone wouldn't mind taking a quick look and letting me know if I made a dumb mistake.

here is my angular code:

```
function locateController($scope, $http) {
            $scope.init = function () {
                $http.get('@(Url.Action<WorkorderController>(c => c.GetLocateNumbers(Model.Id)))').success(function (data) {
                    $scope.model = data;
                    $scope.locateNumber = $scope.locateNumbers();

                    $("#loading").css('display', 'none');
                    $("#ctrl").css('visibility', 'visible');
                    $scope.master = angular.copy($scope.model);
                });
            };

            $scope.init();

            $scope.reset = function () {
                if (confirm('Are you sure you want to discard all your changes?')) {
                    $scope.model = angular.copy($scope.master);
                    $(".selected").removeClass("selected");

                    $scope.locateNumber = $scope.locateNumbers();
                };
            };

            $scope.removeLocate = function (remove) {
                if (confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this location number?')) {
                    var oldLines = $scope.locateNumber;
                    $scope.labor = [];
                    angular.forEach(oldLines, function (line) {
                        if (line != remove) $scope.locateNumber.push(line);
                    });
                }
            };

            $scope.locateNumbers = function () {
                if (!$scope.model) {
                    return null;
                }

                var lines = [];
                angular.forEach($scope.model, function (item) {
                    if (item.IsActive) {
                        lines.push(item);
                    }
                });
                return lines;
            };

            $scope.addLocateLine = function () {
                $scope.locateNumber.push({
                    locationNum: ''
                });
            };

            $scope.dirty = function () {
                if ($scope.model === undefined) {
                    return false;
                }
                var isDirty = !angular.equals($scope.locateNumber, $scope.master.locateNumbers);
                if (isDirty) {
                    $scope.notice = null;
                }
                return isDirty;
            };

            $scope.save = function () {
                $scope.model.Size = $scope.locateNumber.length;
                $scope.model.locateNumbers = $scope.locateNumber;

                $http({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: '@(Url.Action<WorkorderController>(c => c.AssignLocate(Model.Id,null)))',
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": 'application/json',
                        Accepts: 'application/json'
                    },
                    data: { wo: $scope.model }
                }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.init();
                }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    alert('An error has occurred. Please try again later or contact an administrator');
                });
            };
        };
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="modal hide" id="assignLocate" data-ng-controller="locateController">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
        <h3 class="addRow">Locate Number <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-mini" data-ng-click="addLocateLine()">Add</button></h3>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="span3 offset1">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="25" border="0" class="table" id="locateNumbers">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Locate Number</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="num in locateNumber">
                        <td>
                            <ng-form name="LocateNum">
                                <input type="text" ng-model="num.LocateNum" class="span2" required name="Input"/>
                                <span class="alert-error" ng-show="LocatenNum.Input.$error.required"><strong>*Required</strong></span>
                            </ng-form>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-mini btn-danger" ng-click="removeLocate(line)">Remove</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <br /><br />
            <div>
                <div class="span3" style="padding-bottom:25px; margin-left: 0px">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse" ng-click="reset()" ng-disabled="!dirty()">Reset</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-disabled="form.$invalid" ng-click="save()" ng-disabled="!dirty()">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is a js fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/exmMY/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are issues that I've noticed:

1. There is no 'ng-app' in HTML.
2. `locateNumbers` function sometimes returns `null`, but other parts of code expect `locateNumber` to be array.

I didn't excepted further functionality. Changed your sample could be found here: http://plnkr.co/edit/A52VmYLznpNqMLq4XLK0?p=preview

Comment: My main issue ended up being that I had 2 ng-app's. But your comments are still true. Thanks for taking the time to answer.